# Current children have parent serial marked in location, wanting to update records for new method

Tags: sql, database, ssms

The old excel document that we mirrored to a DB had the children's location marked with the serial number of the parent and the parent has the actual location of the object.

Now that we have more time, I am trying to update the data to be structured better. The current table is:

```
object_ID | Serial | Location | Parent_ID
1         | 123    | AAA      | null
2         | AAA    | 207B     | null
3         | 111    | BBB      | null
4         | 222    | BBB      | null
5         | BBB    | 198C     | null
```

The idea would be to find if the Location's value is a serial number, and if so, copy that serial number's object_ID into the parent_ID THEN replace the location with the parent's location. So the output would look something like:

```
object_ID | Serial | Location | Parent_ID
1         | 123    | 207B     | 2
2         | AAA    | 207B     | null
3         | 111    | 198C     | 5         
4         | 222    | 198C     | 5         
5         | BBB    | 198C     | null
```

This is really the furthest I can get without getting lost and confused as to how to write the query.

```
SELECT object_ID, Serial, Location, Parent_ID FROM equipments WHERE Location IN (SELECT Serial FROM equipments)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want a query, you can use:

```
select e.object_id, e.serial, coalesce(ep.location, e.location), e.id as parent_id
from equipments e left join
     equipments ep
     on ep.serial = e.location;
```

If you want an `update`, you can use:

```
update e
    set location = ep.location,
        parent_id = ep.id
    from equipments e join
         equipments ep
         on ep.serial = e.location;
```